# Identifying Grassland surrounded by Woodland

Tags: land-cover, tools

I am trying to identify patches of grassland that is surrounded or mostly enclosed by woodland. I want to find glades and pastures which are sheltered from the wind. Can anyone think of any tool that could be used to do this if I have a raster of a land cover dataset?

Comment: Which software do you use. Please see also [tour] for how to ask a question.

Comment: Sounds like basic classification and neighbour analysis - both tasks are sufficiently documented on the web. What have you tried following any tutorial, and where are you stuck?